# Check if a date was picked via textfield and date picker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I have 2 text fields in my storyboard. One for username, the other one to pick a date. However, I am trying to validate the if the user has a specific amount of characters in the username:

```
func addTargetToTextField() {

    registerUserNameText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}
```

and

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange() {

    let isText = registerUserNameText.text?.count ?? 0 > 3

    if isText { ... etc
```

I am trying to copy that methods on my date picker text field, but it is not working. Im not a Swift expert, but I think it is because the user picks a date and not writing something in the textfield.

How can I check if a date in the textfield was picked?

Comment: You have a textfield whose inputView is datepicker. right ? and now you want to check if user has picked any date or not.  Have i got the question right?

Comment: Just change your method declaration `@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {` and switch the textField to check which one is calling your method `switch textField {` `case registerUserNameText:` and so on

Comment: Yes, Keshu Rai.

Comment: The problem is „ editingChanged“ will not be called, because there is no editing when I use the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `addTarget` method of my `DatePicker` and not the `TextField`  using `.valueChanged` and it is working now.